# Block enter for select rich:suggestionBox

Tags: jsf, richfaces, autosuggest

I use the tag rich:suggestionBox from richFaces 3.3.3 to have a smart research.

But I would like to block the possibility for the user to select an item with the key enter.

I don't find how to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to block the action from the enter key you may want to use event.keyCode == 13,
13 is the key Code for Enter key action from the keyboard.

You may put it in the onsubmit attribute of your rich:suggestionBox like this.

```
onsubmit="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false}"
```

Whenever the user press enter it will not be submitted. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I put your javascript code on onkeydown event and it works. Not realy obvious :/